# Android: Reusing embedded views in gridview [Solution Posted]

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview, android-framelayout

I am trying to reuse a framelayout that has an image and textview inside it but I don't think I am doing this right.  The code works and the display is right but the performance is very poor and I believe it is because I creating a new ImageView and TextView every time the adapters goes back to the item position.

Can someone tell me how to reuse the embedded ImageView (called i) and TextView (called t) without creating new objects?  I am very new to Java and this is my attempt at building a Android application.

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

            FrameLayout F;
            FrameLayout ImageBorder;
            FrameLayout TextBG;

            ImageView i;
            TextView t;

            if(convertView == null) {
                F = new FrameLayout(mContext);

            } else {
                F = (FrameLayout) convertView;
            }

            ImageBorder = new FrameLayout(F.getContext());
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,300,Gravity.BOTTOM);
            ImageBorder.setLayoutParams(params1);

            i = new ImageView(F.getContext()); 
            TextBG = new FrameLayout(F.getContext());
            t = new TextView(F.getContext());

            F.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            ImageBorder.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            ImageBorder.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,40,Gravity.BOTTOM);

            TextBG.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextBG.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            TextBG.setAlpha(.6f);

            t.setLayoutParams(params);

            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            String pathToPhoto = FileList.get(position).toString();
            String fileDescription = pathToPhoto.replaceAll("/mnt/external1/PaliPhotography/","");

            fileDescription = fileDescription.replaceAll(".jpg","");
            fileDescription = fileDescription.toUpperCase();


            Bitmap bm = Cache.getCacheFile("thumb",pathToPhoto);

             if (bm == null) {
                ImageDownloader downloader = new ImageDownloader(i);
                downloader.execute("thumb", pathToPhoto, "400", "400");
             } else {

                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

                t.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
                t.setText(" " + fileDescription);

             }

             ImageBorder.addView(i);
             ImageBorder.addView(TextBG);
             ImageBorder.addView(t);

             F.addView(ImageBorder);

             return F;  

        }  
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

**[EDIT]**

**--------------------------- SOLUTION -----------------------------------------------------**

Here is solution that I implemented based on the feedback below! Thank you!

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

            View ReturnThisView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            LayoutInflater inflater;
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            if(convertView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ReturnThisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagecell, null);
                ReturnThisView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                ReturnThisView = convertView;
            }

            holder.TextDescription = (TextView) ReturnThisView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoDesc);
            holder.ImageThumbnail = (ImageView) ReturnThisView.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

            String pathToPhoto = FileList.get(position).toString();
            String fileDescription = pathToPhoto.replaceAll("/mnt/external1/PaliPhotography/","");

            fileDescription = fileDescription.replaceAll(".jpg","");
            fileDescription = fileDescription.toUpperCase();

            Bitmap bm = Cache.getCacheFile("thumb",pathToPhoto);

             if (bm == null) {
                ImageDownloader downloader = new ImageDownloader(holder.ImageThumbnail);
                downloader.execute("thumb", pathToPhoto, "400", "400");
             } else {

                holder.ImageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bm);
                holder.ImageThumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

                holder.TextDescription.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
                holder.TextDescription.setText(" " + fileDescription);

             }

             return ReturnThisView;
        }  
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
    TextView TextDescription;
    ImageView ImageThumbnail;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instead of dynamically creating your View for each element create an XML layout file, say row.xml.
2. If you detect that `convertView == null` inflate new row by using inflater
3. Locate your TextView and ImageView using View#findViewById
4. Create a Holder object which will help hold references to your newly found TextView and ImageView
5. Save holder as a tag so `convertView.setTag(holder)`
6. For existing convertView find Holder object by doing `holder = convertView.getTag()`
7. Set text and image for these two saved objects, e.g. `holder.txt.setText("Foo")`
8. Android adapter will do the rest as far as reusing instances of inflated rows

Arguably even for your code you can do view initialization and layout once and use Holder pattern to avoid re-initialization of the elements but I think XML will give you better experience

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I have this solution half way implemented already but I have no clue what a holder object is and how to implement.  Is is an object that will allow me to hold both the Image and the Text view in itself?  I tried to search for an explanation and couldn't find any good information on using Holder objects.

Comment: Just to reiterate - Holder (or whatever name you decide to give it) is a simple POJO (data) object that holds the references. In complicated situations I usually add some behavior to the Holder such as reset() method

Answer (score 0):

The solution you provided is not accurate. The ViewHolder is mainly used to avoid inflating the view and calling findViewById() more than once.

**In your code,**

- You should not create a new holder object every time! Instead, you should create a new viewholder only when your convertView = null, then save it in the ReturnThisView tag. If the convertView is not null, then you should load that viewholder you saved before.
- You avoided inflating the view, so well done (y), but you still use findViewById(). Only use findViewById() when convertView = null and you are initializing the views in the view holder. If convertView is not null, then just use the saved views in the viewHolder object you loaded.

**Here is an example:**

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

        View ReturnThisView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater;


        if(convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ReturnThisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagecell, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.TextDescription = (TextView) ReturnThisView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoDesc);
            holder.ImageThumbnail = (ImageView) ReturnThisView.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);
            ReturnThisView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            ReturnThisView = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder)ReturnThisView.getTag();
        }



        String pathToPhoto = FileList.get(position).toString();
        String fileDescription = pathToPhoto.replaceAll("/mnt/external1/PaliPhotography/","");

        fileDescription = fileDescription.replaceAll(".jpg","");
        fileDescription = fileDescription.toUpperCase();

        Bitmap bm = Cache.getCacheFile("thumb",pathToPhoto);

         if (bm == null) {
            ImageDownloader downloader = new ImageDownloader(holder.ImageThumbnail);
            downloader.execute("thumb", pathToPhoto, "400", "400");
         } else {

            holder.ImageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bm);
            holder.ImageThumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            holder.TextDescription.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            holder.TextDescription.setText(" " + fileDescription);

         }

         return ReturnThisView;
    }  
}

static class ViewHolder {
TextView TextDescription;
ImageView ImageThumbnail;
```

}

I learned it from this [site](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).